# How to use JSmooth to convert a .exe back to a jar/.java?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, executable, jsmooth

I wrote a java program (using BlueJay, if that's important) that had only one class. I used JSmooth to convert the program into a .exe, and the .exe works great (only when it's in the folder the .java was originally in, but oh well). The problem, it removed all of the code in the .java and replaced it with JSmooth commands:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<jsmoothproject>
<JVMSearchPath>registry</JVMSearchPath>
<JVMSearchPath>javahome</JVMSearchPath>
<JVMSearchPath>jrepath</JVMSearchPath>
<JVMSearchPath>jdkpath</JVMSearchPath>
<JVMSearchPath>exepath</JVMSearchPath>
<JVMSearchPath>jview</JVMSearchPath>
<arguments></arguments>
<classPath>CubingCalc.java</classPath>
<embeddedJar>false</embeddedJar>
<executableName>CubingCalc.exe</executableName>
<initialMemoryHeap>33554432</initialMemoryHeap>
<mainClassName>CubingCalc</mainClassName>
<maximumMemoryHeap>134217728</maximumMemoryHeap>
<maximumVersion></maximumVersion>
<minimumVersion>1.2</minimumVersion>
<skeletonName>Console Wrapper</skeletonName>
<skeletonProperties>
<key>Message</key>
<value>Java has not been found on your computer.</value>
</skeletonProperties>
<skeletonProperties>
<key>PressKey</key>
<value>0</value>
</skeletonProperties>
<skeletonProperties>
<key>Debug</key>
<value>0</value>
</skeletonProperties>
</jsmoothproject>
```

So my dilemma is that I got the .exe but my only copy of the original .java code was deleted. I saw something somewhere but couldn't find out more about using JSmooth to return a .exe back into it's original java code. How do I do this?

Comment: Most likely you can't. You may be able to retrieve the `.class` files, but not the original `.java` code.

Comment: Yah, most of the time you won't be able to. Anyway, in the first place ; you don't need to create an exe to run it. Just create a jar file which runs fine.